# Creating objects w/ arrays in Javascript and Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a table of responses from a Google Spreadsheet that I've used Google apps scripting to turn into an array that looks something like this

```
Object |  number | Person
--------------------------
A      |   1     | John
A      |   3     | Mary
A      |   2     | Frank
B      |   7     | Joe
B      |   8     | Julie
```

From this array, I'd like to make a new data structure where each object is an entry in the array, and the numbers and people are array objects, like this

```
 Object |  number | Person
  A     |  [1,3,2]| [John, Mary, Frank]
  B     |  [7,8]  | [Joe, Julie]
```

I thought the way to do this was to create a new javascript object and assign properties to the object, like this

```
objectList =[];
thing= {};
thing.name = A;
thing.number = [];
thing.number.push(1);
thing.number.push(3);
thing.number.push(2);
thing.people = [John, Mary, Frank];
objectList.push(thing);
```

But this generates an error when I run the Google App Script that:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property "number" of undefined to "(class@aa14730)"``
```

The error is associated with this code:

```
thing.number=[];
thing.number.push(1);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Here's the actual code I'm using:

```js
function readTripleData(d, c){
//d is the input data, c is the class
//reads 3-12 in the array
  
  c.important=[];
  c.important.push(Number(d[3]));
  
  c.comfortable=[];
  c.comfortable.push(Number(d[4]));

  c.involved=[];
  c.involved.push(Number(d[5]));
  
  c.team=[];
  c.team.push(Number(d[6]));
  
  c.goodWork=[];
  c.goodWork.push(Number(d[7]));
  
    
  c.stand=[];
  c.stand.push(Number(d[8]));
  
  
  
  c.thoughtProvoking=[];
  c.thoughtProvoking.push(Number(d[9]));
  
   
  c.effective=[];
  c.effective.push(Number(d[10]));
 
  c.easy=[];
  c.easy.push(Number(d[11]));
  
   
  c.little=[];
  c.little.push(Number(d[12]));
}


function buildClassArray(d)
{
  var courseList=[];
  var courseCount = 0;
  var currentTeacher ="";
  var currentClass = "";
  Logger.log("d.length = "+d.length);
  for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++)
  {
    if(currentTeacher == d[i][1] && currentClass == d[i][2]) 
    {
      //eval is part of class--add to current entry (which is courseCount -1 in the array
      readTripleData(d[i], courseList[i-1]);
      readNarrativeFeedback(d[i],courseList[i-1]);
      
  
    }
    else
    {
      //eval is not part of class-create a new entry in courseList
      currentTeacher = d[i][1];
      currentClass = d[i][2];
      var course = {teacher: currentTeacher, class: currentClass}
      
      Logger.log("in else branch");
      readTripleData(d[i], course);
      
      courseList.push(course);
      courseCount++;
    }
      
      
      
  }
  //should return an array of class array data 
  Logger.log ("courseCount is "+courseCount);
  return courseList;
  
  
}

function writeEvaluations()
{
 
 var data = data =["2/2/17","Teacher Name", 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7 ,8, 9, 10 ,4, 11];

 courseData = buildClassArray(data);
 
 Logger.log("You have "+ courseData.length + " courses") ;
 Logger.log("important :"+ courseData[0].important);
  
 //readClass(range, 0);

}
```

Comment: Fixed the typo—it was correct in my actual code, and I also had thing declared as an object. I think I do want thing.number to be an array, and that's where I'm getting the error.

Comment: That code looks fine. Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I put the code in a snippet, but it's generating an error when I run the snippet that I don't understand.

Comment: On the `var data = data = ["2/2/17"...` line, you were missing a comma between `8` and `9`. (If you looked in the web console when you run the snippet, it would point you right at the error.) I've fixed it for you, but now the snippet doesn't do anything as far as I can see.

Comment: Since I'd gotten stuck at the error referenced above, I haven't added code to use the courseData array that is constructed, but the  Logger.log("important :"+ courseData[0].important) line should output the important property in Google Apps Script.

Comment: I guess I'm wondering if there's an easier way to parse data like this—moving from an array of responses associated with objects, to an array of objects that have each of the responses as a property.